# torchmetrics behaviour for one-hot encoded values

Tags: pytorch, metrics

I am having a hard time understanding the following scenario. I have a output probability of 0.0 on each class which means value of metrics such as f1 score, accuracy and recall should be zero? However i get the following:

```
import torch, torchmetrics
preds = torch.tensor([[0., 0., 0.],
                      [0., 0., 0.],
                      [0., 0., 0.]])

target = torch.tensor([[1, 0, 0],
                       [0, 1, 0],
                       [0, 0, 1]])

print("F1: ", torchmetrics.functional.f1_score(preds, target))
print("Accuracy: ", torchmetrics.functional.accuracy(preds, target))
print("Recall: ", torchmetrics.functional.recall(preds, target))
print("Precision: ", torchmetrics.functional.precision(preds, target))
```

Output:

```
F1:  tensor(0.)
Accuracy:  tensor(0.6667)
Recall:  tensor(0.)
Precision:  tensor(0.)
```

Why is accuracy 0.6667? I would expect all outputs to be 0.0.

Comment: preds are a multi-label array, not multi-class probabilities array, do you know that?

Comment: @Phoenix I see, this was the root cause of my misunderstanding.

Comment: Exactly, this was my guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `preds` is a probabilities array for multi-label classification problem:

To make it simpler, I will assume the example like that:

```
preds = torch.tensor([[0., 0., 0.]]) # multi-labels [label1, label2, label3]

target = torch.tensor([[1, 0, 0]])
```

**The true negatives** are **2** since classifier predicts not existence for `label2` and `label3` while label2 and label3 indeed should not be existed.

**The true positives** are **0** since classifier predicts the existence of any label while a label should be existed.

**The false negative** is **1** since classifier predicts no existence for `label1` while  `label1` should be existed.

**The false positives** are **0** since classifier predicts any label while a label should not be existed.

[image]

**According to the above equation, Accuracy = 2/3 = 0.6667**

You can read [here](https://medium.com/synthesio-engineering/precision-accuracy-and-f1-score-for-multi-label-classification-34ac6bdfb404) more about different metrics and their calculations.